# 7 segment display malfunctioning with ATmega8A

Tags: arduino, atmega, 7segmentdisplay

I am using an ATmega8A and want to take 8-bit input and display the corresponding binary in decimal form on three 7-segment displays but when I do it some unwanted segments light up dimly. What can be the issue?

I am using resistors for the inputs for the microcontroller and the segments of the display and also the common cathode. Here is the code that I am using.

```c
// Pin Definitions
#define SWITCH_PIN_0 2
#define SWITCH_PIN_1 3
#define SWITCH_PIN_2 4
#define SWITCH_PIN_3 5
#define SWITCH_PIN_4 6
#define SWITCH_PIN_5 7
#define SWITCH_PIN_6 8
#define SWITCH_PIN_7 9

#define COMMON_PIN_1 10
#define COMMON_PIN_2 11
#define COMMON_PIN_3 12

#define SEGMENT_A 13
#define SEGMENT_B A0
#define SEGMENT_C A1
#define SEGMENT_D A2
#define SEGMENT_E A3
#define SEGMENT_F A4
#define SEGMENT_G A5

// Define segment patterns for 0-9
const byte digitPatterns[10] = {
B00111111, //0
B00000110, //1
B01011011, //2
B01001111, //3
B01100110, //4
B01101101, //5
B01111101, //6
B00000111, //7
B01111111, //8
B01101111, //9
};

// Variables
byte dipSwitchValue = 0;

void setup() {
  // Initialize pin modes
  pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_0, INPUT);
  pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_1, INPUT);
  pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_2, INPUT);
  pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_3, INPUT);
  pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_4, INPUT);
  pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_5, INPUT);
  pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_6, INPUT);
  pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_7, INPUT);
  
  pinMode(COMMON_PIN_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(COMMON_PIN_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(COMMON_PIN_3, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(SEGMENT_A, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SEGMENT_B, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SEGMENT_C, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SEGMENT_D, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SEGMENT_E, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SEGMENT_F, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SEGMENT_G, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // Read the dip switch value
  dipSwitchValue = digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_7) << 7 |
                   digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_6) << 6 |
                   digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_5) << 5 |
                   digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_4) << 4 |
                   digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_3) << 3 |
                   digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_2) << 2 |
                   digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_1) << 1 |
                   digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_0);

  // Display the value on the 7-segment displays
  displayValue(dipSwitchValue);

  delay(10);  // Adjust the delay as needed
}

// Function to display a value on the 7-segment displays
void displayValue(byte value) {
  // Separate each digit
  byte digit1 = value / 100;
  byte digit2 = (value / 10) % 10;
  byte digit3 = value % 10;

  // Turn on the common pins for each digit
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_3, HIGH);
  
  // Display digit 1
  displayDigit(digit1);

  delayMicroseconds(1000);

  // Turn on the common pins for each digit
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_3, HIGH);

  // Display digit 2
  displayDigit(digit2);

  delayMicroseconds(1000);

  // Turn on the common pins for each digit
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_3, LOW);

  // Display digit 3
  displayDigit(digit3);

  delayMicroseconds(1000);
}

// Function to display a digit on the 7-segment display
void displayDigit(byte digit) {
  // Set the segment pins based on the digit pattern
  digitalWrite(SEGMENT_A, bitRead(digitPatterns[digit], 0));
  digitalWrite(SEGMENT_B, bitRead(digitPatterns[digit], 1));
  digitalWrite(SEGMENT_C, bitRead(digitPatterns[digit], 2));
  digitalWrite(SEGMENT_D, bitRead(digitPatterns[digit], 3));
  digitalWrite(SEGMENT_E, bitRead(digitPatterns[digit], 4));
  digitalWrite(SEGMENT_F, bitRead(digitPatterns[digit], 5));
  digitalWrite(SEGMENT_G, bitRead(digitPatterns[digit], 6));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a code error. In order to avoid the ghosting issue I added a blank cycle where each digit is first turned off completely before feeding in a new value.
Here is the updated code:

```
//Pin definations
#define SWITCH_PIN_0 9
#define SWITCH_PIN_1 10
#define SWITCH_PIN_2 11
#define SWITCH_PIN_3 12
#define SWITCH_PIN_4 13
#define SWITCH_PIN_5 A0
#define SWITCH_PIN_6 A1
#define SWITCH_PIN_7 A2

#define COMMON_PIN_1 A5
#define COMMON_PIN_2 A4
#define COMMON_PIN_3 A3

#define SEGMENT_A 2
#define SEGMENT_B 3
#define SEGMENT_C 4
#define SEGMENT_D 5
#define SEGMENT_E 6
#define SEGMENT_F 7
#define SEGMENT_G 8

// Define segment patterns for 0-9
const byte digitPatterns[10] = {
B00111111, //0
B00000110, //1
B01011011, //2
B01001111, //3
B01100110, //4
B01101101, //5
B01111101, //6
B00000111, //7
B01111111, //8
B01101111, //9
};

// Variables
byte dipSwitchValue = 0;

void setup() {
// Initialize pin modes
pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_0, INPUT);
pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_1, INPUT);
pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_2, INPUT);
pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_3, INPUT);
pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_4, INPUT);
pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_5, INPUT);
pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_6, INPUT);
pinMode(SWITCH_PIN_7, INPUT);

pinMode(COMMON_PIN_1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(COMMON_PIN_2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(COMMON_PIN_3, OUTPUT);

pinMode(SEGMENT_A, OUTPUT);
pinMode(SEGMENT_B, OUTPUT);
pinMode(SEGMENT_C, OUTPUT);
pinMode(SEGMENT_D, OUTPUT);
pinMode(SEGMENT_E, OUTPUT);
pinMode(SEGMENT_F, OUTPUT);
pinMode(SEGMENT_G, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
// Read the dip switch value
dipSwitchValue = digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_7) << 7 |
               digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_6) << 6 |
               digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_5) << 5 |
               digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_4) << 4 |
               digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_3) << 3 |
               digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_2) << 2 |
               digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_1) << 1 |
               digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN_0);

// Display the value on the 7-segment displays
displayValue(dipSwitchValue);

delay(0.01);  // Adjust the delay as needed
}

void displayValue(byte value) {
// Separate each digit
byte digit1 = value / 100;
byte digit2 = (value / 10) % 10;
byte digit3 = value % 10;

// Turn off all segments
blankCycle();

// Turn on the common pins for each digit
digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_1, LOW);
digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_3, HIGH);

// Display digit 1
displayDigit(digit1);

delay(0.5);

// Turn off all segments
blankCycle();

// Turn on the common pins for each digit
digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_1, HIGH);
digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_2, LOW);
digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_3, HIGH);

// Display digit 2
displayDigit(digit2);

delay(0.5);

// Turn off all segments
blankCycle();

// Turn on the common pins for each digit
digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_1, HIGH);
digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_3, LOW);

// Display digit 3
displayDigit(digit3);

delay(0.5);
}

// Function to display a digit on the 7-segment display
void displayDigit(byte digit) {
// Set the segment pins based on the digit pattern
 digitalWrite(SEGMENT_A, bitRead(digitPatterns[digit], 0));
digitalWrite(SEGMENT_B, bitRead(digitPatterns[digit], 1));
digitalWrite(SEGMENT_C, bitRead(digitPatterns[digit], 2));
digitalWrite(SEGMENT_D, bitRead(digitPatterns[digit], 3));
digitalWrite(SEGMENT_E, bitRead(digitPatterns[digit], 4));
digitalWrite(SEGMENT_F, bitRead(digitPatterns[digit], 5));
digitalWrite(SEGMENT_G, bitRead(digitPatterns[digit], 6));
}
void blankCycle() {
digitalWrite(SEGMENT_A, LOW);
digitalWrite(SEGMENT_B, LOW);
digitalWrite(SEGMENT_C, LOW);
digitalWrite(SEGMENT_D, LOW);
digitalWrite(SEGMENT_E, LOW);
digitalWrite(SEGMENT_F, LOW);
digitalWrite(SEGMENT_G, LOW);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't necessarily complete without a schematic, but I can find two problems with your logic in the source code:

##### Uneven segment brightness

Your expanded logic is basically this:

1. Read input
2. Display segment 1
3. Wait 1 ms
4. Display segment 2
5. Wait 1 ms
6. Display segment 3
7. Wait 1 ms
8. Wait 10 ms
9. GOTO <strike>10</strike> 1

Since you don't turn off segment 3, it will be lit for 11 ms while the other segments are only lit for 1 ms. It will be much brighter. It can be solved by simply adding an extra step to turn it off after 1 ms.

##### "Contention" on the columns

I can't come up with the correct term but your display code ends like this:

```
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_3, LOW);
```

... and starts like this ...

```
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_1, LOW);
  // oops!
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(COMMON_PIN_3, HIGH);
  // phew!
```

The place that I've marked will have both `COMMON_PIN_3` low at the same time as `COMMON_PIN_1`, meaning that for a fraction the current will flow through both segment 1 and segment 3. This will probably be less than a microsecond, and I don't think that's the problem here, but it might be and it's something to avoid in general.

Comment: Thanks for the response turns out it was a ghosting issue which was solved by adding a blank cycle

Answer (score 0):

If you have transistors driving the LEDs, they do not turn off immediately and that can cause ghosting.

Even if you don't have transistors, you turn off digit and turn on the next digit while still having the same segments on before you update the digits.

Also the change from last digit to first has both the last and first digit enabled with segments of the last digit before last digit is turned off.

Comment: Thanks for the response turns out it was a ghosting issue which was solved by adding a blank cycle. BTW how do I create one using a transistor as you mentioned in your answer.